# Aligning a text in middle next to an image?

Tags: html, css, browser, html-table

I have a table column like this, where I want to align an image and a text.
The text must be in the middle of the image.

```
<td><img height='50px' src='blabla'>Hello</td>
```

The above aligns the text at the bottom of the image.

I have also tried adding `vertical-align:middle` to the td style property, without luck.

I have also tried adding a `<font>` and styling that to `vertical-align:middle` without luck.

I know of one way, and that is adding another table column and having the text and image in separate columns, then it would be possible to align the text vertically in the middle, but I am trying to avoid this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the `vertical-align` to the img, not the `td`:

```
<td>
  <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="test.jpg"/>
  test
</td>
```

To apply the style to all images in `td`s, use an external CSS:

```
td img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using valign="middle"

```
<td valign="middle"><img height='50px' src='blabla'>Hello</td>
```

Also, no need to add "px" to the height of the img.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img height='50' width='50' src='http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png' style='vertical-align:middle;">Hello</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDRy8/

Answer (score 0):

use `vertical-align:middle` on the image and not the `td`

```
td img{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

working example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/pPVtH/

Answer (score -1):

Add vertical-align to the row as well, not just the cell.

Comment: Why would you vertically align the 'row'? Its the image that needs aligning

Comment: I always do that so the cells inside of it inherit the property. Also add "vertical-align: middle" to the IMG tag and you should be good.